# Needing advanced ID3 tag handling for specific situation

Tags: mp3, id3, batch-rename

My situation is probably quite rare and complex, so I'll explain it in detail.

Many years ago, I put together a hand-selected collection of MP3s, which ended up taking a month or so and is now at 8000 songs. All of these songs were manually ID3 tagged, which took me forever. Unfortunately, I had a strange tagging philosophy. For songs that featured multiple artists, I would put the features in the Artist field, rather than the Title field. Here's what I mean:

> What I have: OB O'Brien (ft. Drake) - 2 On/Thotful
>
> What every normal person has: OB O'Brien - 2 On/Thotful (ft. Drake)

Is there any software or script that handles ID3 tags that will let me perform an advanced renaming like this? Basically, I want to batch handle my MP3s so that if "(ft. *)" is found in the Artist field, it is removed and instead appended to the end of the Title field. Possible?

Comment: Check out http://beets.io They have a specific plugin called FtInTitle that does exactly this: http://beets.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.1/plugins/ftintitle.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Please try [Mp3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/).
In the associated [forum](http://forums.mp3tag.de/index.php?showtopic=12513&st=15#entry65148) you will find many examples how to add own "Actions" that exactly do what you want:

- Check a specific tag (like Artist or AlbumArtist) for a specific string (like "ft.")
- If found, do something with the catch, like moving this part to another tag

You can even use Regular Expressions, like

`Action: Guess values
Source format:
%ARTIST%$regexp(%TITLE%,'^(.+?)\s+[[({<]?\s*(?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?)\s*([^])}>]+)\>\s*[])}>]?(.*)$',' feat. $2$3+++$1',1)
... or ...
%ARTIST%$regexp(%TITLE%,'^(.+?)\s+[[({<]?\s*(?:featuring|feat\.?|ft\.?)\s*([^])}>]+)[])}>]?(.*)$',' feat. $2$3+++$1',1)
Guessing pattern:
%ARTIST%+++%TITLE%`

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I'm trying to follow your instructions. I get this far: http://puu.sh/8XzX3.png

Upon confirming, I'm taken by to this step: http://puu.sh/8XzZU.png - What should I do from there?

Comment: In your second print screen, you can add a new Action Group (pressing the Button with the yellow star icon). Then you give a name for your own Action Group like "Move Feat from Artist to Title". Then add the above source format and guessing pattern as you did in print screen #1. Save your Action Group with OK. Then select one of your mp3 tracks and press the Button for Actions (Big Blue A with little green a). Select only your newly added Action Group and press "OK". Check, if the action make the modification as you expected. If yes, select all the tracks of an album that you want to modify.